# Internet Explorer percent based layout issue

Tags: css, html, tablelayout

My goal is to make a layout that is 200% width and height, with four containers of equal height and width (100% each), using no javascript as the bear minimum (or preferably no hacks).

Right now I am using HTML5, and CSS display:table. It works fine in Safari 4, Firefox 3.5, and Chrome 5. I haven't tested it yet on older versions.

Nonetheless, in IE7 and IE8 this layout fails completely. (I do use the Javascript HTML5 enabling script /*cc..*/, so it should not be the use of new HTML5 tags)

Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>IE issue with layout</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
            /* styles */
            @import url("reset.css");

            /* Generall CSS */          
            .table
            {
                display:table;
            }

            .row
            {
                display:table-row;
            }

            .cell
            {
                display:table-cell;
            }


            /* Specific CSS */
            html, body
            {
                //overflow:hidden; I later intend to limit the viewport
            }

            section#body
            {
                position:absolute;
                width:200%;
                height:200%;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            section#body .row
            {
                width:200%;
                height:50%;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            section#body .row .cell
            {
                width:50%;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            section#body .row .cell section
            {
                display:block;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            section#body #stage0 section header
            {
                text-align:center;
                height:20%;
                display:block;
            }

            section#body #stage0 section footer
            {
                display:block;
                height:80%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="body" class="table">
            <section class="row">
                <section id="stage0" class="cell">
                    <section>
                        <header>
                            <form>
                                <input type="text" name="q" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                            </form>
                        </header>
                        <footer>
                            <table id="scrollers">
                            </table>
                        </footer>
                    </section>
                </section>
                <section id="stage1" class="cell">
                    <section>
                        content
                    </section>
                </section>          
            </section>
            <section class="row">
                <section id="stage2" class="cell">
                    <section>
                        content
                    </section>
                </section>
                <section id="stage3" class="cell">
                    <section>
                        content
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see it live here: http://www.tombarrasso.com/ie-issue/

Comment: just a note, `//` isn't valid comment syntax in CSS - only `/* ... */` is valid in CSS.

Comment: Looking in the IE8 dev tools, it looks like IE completely fails to "nest" your HTML5 tags.  I'm not sure if that is just the dev tools acting up, or if it is accurately reflecting what IE has "interpreted" your code as. (It works in IE9 Dev Preview 1 by the way)

Comment: Turns out if I added the /*@cc_on...*/ into a script tag in the head, and not an external file, it works in IE8 as it should. However the layout itself behaves differently in IE7, one cell takes up the entire 200% and no other content is shown.

Comment: Well I have gotten even further. Turns out IE7 does not support display:table and such. I am almost there, with the exception that IE7 has an issue with percentages. 200% height leads to two lines in IE7 (in IE8 and all others it is fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Turns out there were many issues.

One is that this `/*@cc_on'abbr article aside audio canvas details figcaption figure footer header hgroup mark menu meter nav output progress section summary time video'.replace(/\w+/g,function(n){document.createElement(n)});@*/` comment is required in a script tag within the head of the document.

Secondly, IE7 and below to not recognize `display:table` or the like, see [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Lastly, the html, body elements needed to have height:100% so that IE knows what to refer to.

Anyway, this is fixed and works great.